# How can I prohibit executable files in a Samba share?

Tags: linux, samba

I want to setup a Samba share for file sharing in my intranet.

1. Is there any way to prohibit some kinds of files (e.g *.exe) from being uploaded to the share folder?
2. How can I force the user to change their password when logging in for the first time?

Comment: Yes it is possible. I do not have full answer but hint is use `veto files` option in your configuration file for your first query, which will hide the specified files. Hint for second query is to use `pdedit` utility.

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to file/directory permissions, remember that Samba **maps** Windows bits to Unix bits.

The Windows' `archive` bit is mapped to the execute bit. If you want to create files without the `x` bit, do this:

```
[global]
    map archive = no
```

More on permissions: https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/using_samba/ch08.html

Comment: I think the question is asking how can they stop someone from putting files with a certain extension on the file server, not so much how to stop them from executing the file (which can also be done through normal file permissions via `chmod 400 file`)

Comment: From my Googling an issue with not wanting my files to be +x when some were shared over samba for Windows devs, this *really* helped me out. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found a great tutorial on this from [RedHatLinux](http://www.redhatlinux.info/2011/11/configure-samba-server.html).

**CONFIGURE SAMBA SERVER**

```
Step 1.mkdir /samba
Step 2.chmod a+w /samba
Step 3.yum install samba -y
Step 4.vim /etc/samba/smb.conf
    [public]
        comment = Only users
        path = /samba
        public = yes
        browseable=yes
        writable = yes
        printable = no
        write list = +staff
Step 5.service smb restart
```

**OPTIONS THAT CAN BE GIVEN IN FILE**

```
Step 1.If browseable=yes ->we CAN see the shared dir
  If browseable=no -> we CANNOT see the shared dir
Step 2.If public=yes    ->Allows anonymous Login
  If public=no     ->Stops  anonymous Login
Step 3.writable = no     ->uploading is denied  for BOTH the users.
   writable = yes    ->uploading is allowed for BOTH the users
Step 4
     a. writable =no +   ->Allows only u1 to upload files, but
     b. write list =u1   both writable=no and writelist=u1 shuld b enabled
Step 5.hosts allow=127. 192.168.0.20 ->Allow only 192.168.0.20 ip to access share, other ips are denied
```

**CLIENT COMMANDS**

```
Step 1.smbclient -L //192.168.0.48/share  ->List directories shared
Step 2. smbclient //192.168.0.48/share   ->Anonymous Login
   get <file>
   put <file>     
Step 3a. To generat passwd to allow for non-anonymous login
      1. smbpasswd -a u1
      2. service smb restart 
Step 3b. smbclient //192.168.0.48/share -U u1  ->Non Anonymous Login
    get <file>
    put <file>
```